# jOOQ configuration null when using 'fetch.into(MyClass.class)'

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I needed to upgrade Gradle and some packages in my application, but after that, Spring Boot or jOOQ does not seem to load it's configuration or something similar to that.

Build.gradle important parts:

```
...
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '3.0.3'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
}


dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jooq', version: '2.2.1.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '3.4.1'
    compile group: 'org.firebirdsql.jdbc', name: 'jaybird-jdk18', version: '2.2.12'
    compile group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq', version: '3.12.3'
    compile group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-codegen', version: '3.12.3'

    jooqRuntime 'org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk18:2.2.12'
}


ext['jooq.version'] = '3.12.3'
...
```

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
List<LinhaRelatoFichaProduto> notas =
        dsl.selectFrom(notasEntrada.unionAll(notasSaida).asTable())
                .orderBy(field(name("data")),
                        field(name("tipo")),
                        field(name("numero")),
                        field(name("datahora"))
                ).fetch().into(LinhaRelatoFichaProduto.class);
```

But I get a NullPointerException at this line:

```
@Override
        public final <R extends Record, E> RecordMapper<R, E> provide(final RecordType<R> rowType, final Class<? extends E> type) {
            if (TRUE.equals(configuration.settings().isCacheRecordMappers()))    << HERE! configuration is null for some reason
                return Cache.run(configuration, new CachedOperation<RecordMapper<R, E>>() {
                    @Override
                    public RecordMapper<R, E> call() {
                        return new DefaultRecordMapper<R, E>(rowType, type, configuration);
                    }
                }, DATA_CACHE_RECORD_MAPPERS, Cache.key(rowType, type));
            else
                return new DefaultRecordMapper<R, E>(rowType, type, configuration);
        }
```

And this is the full error stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapperProvider.provide(DefaultRecordMapperProvider.java:83)
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultImpl.into(ResultImpl.java:1369)
    at br.com.tropicalia.service.RelatoFichaProdutoService.start(RelatoFichaProdutoService.java:90)
    at br.com.tropicalia.service.RelatoFichaProdutoService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ac9b0452.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at br.com.tropicalia.service.RelatoFichaProdutoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd439b32.start(<generated>)
    at br.com.tropicalia.ui.MainController.gerarRelatorio(MainController.java:127)
    at br.com.tropicalia.ui.MainController.lambda$initialize$2(MainController.java:79)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

```java
@Override
        public final <R extends Record, E> RecordMapper<R, E> provide(final RecordType<R> rowType, final Class<? extends E> type) {
            if (TRUE.equals(configuration.settings().isCacheRecordMappers()))    << HERE! configuration is null for some reason
                return Cache.run(configuration, new CachedOperation<RecordMapper<R, E>>() {
                    @Override
                    public RecordMapper<R, E> call() {
                        return new DefaultRecordMapper<R, E>(rowType, type, configuration);
                    }
                }, DATA_CACHE_RECORD_MAPPERS, Cache.key(rowType, type));
            else
                return new DefaultRecordMapper<R, E>(rowType, type, configuration);
        }
```

My custom DSL context:

```
@Configuration
public class FirebirdJooqConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "firebirdDSLContext")
    public DSLContext firebirdDSLContext(@Qualifier("firebirdDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return DSL.using(new DefaultConfiguration()
                .set(dataSource)
                .set(SQLDialect.FIREBIRD)
                .set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(new JooqExceptionTransformer()))
                .set(new DefaultRecordMapperProvider()));
    }

}
```

So... how do I avoid my jOOQ configuration being null?

Comment: Could you please post your complete stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in jOOQ: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9621

Remove your `DefaultRecordMapperProvider` from your `Configuration`, and it should work:

```
@Bean(name = "firebirdDSLContext")
public DSLContext firebirdDSLContext(@Qualifier("firebirdDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return DSL.using(new DefaultConfiguration()
            .set(dataSource)
            .set(SQLDialect.FIREBIRD)
            .set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(new JooqExceptionTransformer()))
         /* .set(new DefaultRecordMapperProvider()) */ );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lukas Eder, God of jOOQ. Your work and support are amazing.